# Airflow using Cronitier

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to use Cronitier to schedule job a monthly job to run every 2 Tuesday. I tried below
This is my partial script.

from croniter import croniter

cron = croniter("00 21 * * 2#2")

dag = DAG('recurring_job', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=cron)
But it didn't work. Would you please help me or give some reference.

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the cron string directly:

```py
dag = DAG('recurring_job', schedule_interval="00 21 * * 2#2")
```

Airflow will translate that using croniter internally.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow supports also `datetime.timedelta` object for `schedule_interval`, see [Scheduling & Triggers](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/scheduler.html#dag-runs):

> Each DAG may or may not have a schedule, which informs how DAG Runs are created. schedule_interval is defined as a DAG arguments, and receives preferably a cron expression as a str, **or a datetime.timedelta object.**

Together with `start_date`, it should work out without the usage of croniter:

```py
dag = DAG('recurring_job', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(weeks=2), start_date = datetime(2020,11,3,21))
```